# How to Display Joomla database table using native joomla 2.5 php objects

Tags: php, mysql, class, object, joomla

I am trying to display data from a MySQL database table using the native joomla PHP objects, however I can never get it to work right. It never displays any data.

I know how to display the data by connecting to the database the old fashion way, like below...

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxx_user10","$dbpass","xxxxxxx_final");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
//What is the base model
$sku = $finish;
// Select The Correct Table
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM BAH_finish WHERE color_value='$sku' GROUP BY uniqueID ORDER BY uniqueID ASC");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $finishname = $row['color_name'];
  $finishtype = $row['color_type'];
```

However i'd like to display content like I have above, but by using the joomla native php objects, so iv'e created a sample php table with the following fields.....

```
| ID | Last | First | Address | City | State | ZIP
```

and tried to display it (ALL ROWS) / OR (ONE ROW) using the following joomla code.....but nothing happens....no matter how I try to switch it up or change out parts of the code....So my thinking is that i'm missing a fundamental part of how this should work....Thanks again for your help! Also please do not quote joomla 2.5 component tutorial from joomla.org...that is where I've gotten this code and IMO it lacks a lot of information.

```
<?php

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Last', 'First', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'ZIP')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('111testnames'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('Last') . $db->quote('buffet'));

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

echo $results;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct: `$query->from($db->quoteName('111testnames'));`

to `$query->from($db->quoteName('#__111testnames'));`

using `#__` automatically adds the suffix of your table.

Another error that I could see is the where clause doesn't have have an operator. Please try to correct it to `$query->where($db->quoteName('Last') ." = ". $db->quote('buffet'));`.

In order to have a proper view of the results you have to use `print_r($results);` instead of `echo $results;` as there is an object array you have to display not a string.

Good Luck!